# Format DateTime object from System time format to required format

Tags: c#, datetime

My system time is of the format `dd-MMM-yy` (02-Dec-16). The format I want to convert it to is `"yyyy/MM/dd"`. I've basically been playing around with all the other datetime formats that my system offers and this is the parsing statement I've figured out that works for All of them (except this) -

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string date_format = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss tt";
DateTime now_value = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString(date_format), date_format, provider);
return now_value.ToString(date_format);
```

But this doesn't work for the aforementioned dd-MMM-yy format. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

(Sidebar -Is there a more efficient way in which I can write this above snippet?)

Comment: `now.ToString(` is it or `now_value.ToString(`

Comment: now_value. Typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to convert DateTime to string and then convert back to DateTime and again back to string, if you have DateTime input just call the ToString with the format as below

```
 string dt =DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MMM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

for your example :

```
DateTime now_value = DateTime.ParseExact("02-Dec-16", "dd-MMM-yy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 return  now_value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

Comment: I've edited my required format. But let me try this with the edited format.

Comment: what is the `provider` you have used in your example?

Comment: The provider is as you've assumed -  "CultureInfo.InvariantCulture".

Comment: Still I'm couldn't get your issue! do you have many possible date time strings with several date time formats? And then you need to parse any of those string datetimes in to DateTime? is that your issue?

Comment: Thanks for your patience! Yes, I need to parse multiple datetime formats into this single format. And all of them need to take the same input i.e Now(). I think your first solution would possibly work for me. I'm trying it out.

Comment: For `DateTime` object there is no format, we can show it as we needed by giving format, default format is taken when there is no format provided.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
string date_format = "yyyy-MMM-dd";
string date_now = DateTime.Now.ToString(date_format,CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
return date_now;
```

Even This should also work:

```
string date_format = "yyyy-MMM-dd";
string date_now = DateTime.Now.ToString(date_format);
return date_now;
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid a specific culture. Consequently I used InvariantCulture. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think best way would be to create an extension method for multiple date formats,

```
var inputDate = "02-Dec-2016";
string[] availaible_input_date_format = { "dd-MMM-yyyy", "dd/MMM/yyyy" }; // add as many formats availible
var date_format = "yyyy/MMM/dd";
DateTime outputDate;
DateTime.TryParseExact(inputDate, availaible_input_date_format, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out outputDate);
Console.WriteLine(outputDate.ToString(date_format));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
datetime yourdatetime = new datetime();
string converteddatetime = yourdatetime.toString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

Comment: This always returns "0001-01-01".

Comment: its just an example abhiii5459.

Comment: use only string converteddatetime = yourdatetime.toString("yyyy/MM/dd");